# What is it about a file type that determines whether or not it can be opened in Excel?

Tags: excel, file, compatibility, dbf

For example, I can open up an .xls file or a .csv file in Excel and it will automatically know it's a valid filetype and have everything associated to the cells cleanly.

However, the same applies to a .DBF file which is a database file. Even though it's not related to Excel in a direct sense, it's still a "compatible" file type that opens up cleanly in Excel.

Contrast that to an arbitrary .DAT file where opening it in Excel either doesn't work or yields gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

That's an implementation detail of Excel.  It may consider the filetype, it may look at the first few bytes of the file, hell it may depend on the phase of the moon.  This behavior has changed over time but has never been documented.